# converting json into jsonp for using it as a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to use a data api. I am still at a very preliminary stage with this so just digging in to understand the basic plumbing. I id some research to check whatare the variables involved and i found out that I have to have some sort of server side scripting to handle cross domain call for json. Basically to convert it into jsonp. Now the the qestion is how. I looked but dont really see a direction which matches my requirement.

Here is the api which is returning in  .json

http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xm9j-adfx.json

And here is a code sample:

```
[ {
  "consumption_gj_" : "83983",
  "zip_code" : {
    "needs_recoding" : false,
    "longitude" : "-73.99688630375988",
    "latitude" : "40.75025902143676",
    "human_address" : "{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"10001\"}"
  },
  "building_type_service_class_" : "Commercial"
}
, {
  "consumption_gj_" : "91967",
  "zip_code" : {
    "needs_recoding" : false,
    "longitude" : "-73.98583147024613",
    "latitude" : "40.71612146793143",
    "human_address" : "{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"10002\"}"
  },
  "building_type_service_class_" : "Commercial"
} ]
```

lets say I would like to print all the zip codes from here

How should I approach this?

Comment: If you use a server to retrieve the data and your page is served from the same server, then you don't need JSONP. The structure of JSONP is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. "How do I tranverse a JSON structure" is not "JSON vs JSONp"

Comment: @Felix is right. If you are proxying the data via your server (on your domain) anyway, you don't need jsonp any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uficuz/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
var allZips = [];

$.getJSON('http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xm9j-adfx.json', function(data) {

  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){    
   allZips.push(  JSON.parse(data[i].zip_code.human_address).zip  );     
  }
  alert( allZips ); // 10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006,10007,......

});
```

You're fine with objects until the last one which is a string with escapes:

```
"human_address" : "{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"10001\"}"
```

that's why you need to first PARSE the data (transform it into JSON) and than retrieve the `zip` value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @hi Roko-- Can you do something about the alert? It is freezing my system. Apparently it is is huge and I cant see anything in there. Can you do something like $allZips.appendTo('<div></div>'); Sorry about this annoying request. Its just that the alert is killing my machine :-)